# Magento : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento

I got below issue when I try to add to cart product (Gift card product)programatically , It's occour first time it mean when I refresh the page then It's working fine as excepted
For Regenerate this issue I need to create new website and follow the process

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sales_flat_quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_SALES_FLAT_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_quote` (`entity_id`) ON ), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_address` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `customer_id`, `address_type`, `same_as_billing`, `free_shipping`, `weight`, `subtotal`, `base_subtotal`, `tax_amount`, `base_tax_amount`, `shipping_amount`, `base_shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`, `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `discount_amount`, `base_discount_amount`, `grand_total`, `base_grand_total`, `applied_taxes`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `shipping_incl_tax`, `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `base_customer_balance_amount`, `customer_balance_amount`, `gift_cards_amount`, `base_gift_cards_amount`, `gift_cards`, `used_gift_cards`) VALUES (?, '2016-10-03 08:29:30', '2016-10-03 08:29:30', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Can anyone please update how can we fixed this issue

Our Magento Version : 1.14.2.2